# How to delete all frames in H2O?

Tags: h2o

I accidently imported more data into 0xdata's h2o flow than I actually intended. How can I delete all my data frames?

I already tried `Data -> List All Frames -> Delete`, but I get the following error message:

> Error evaluating cell
>
> Error calling DELETE/....ink
>
> Object 'nfs:....lnk' not found for argument: key

Is there another way to erase those data frames? Where are those data frames physically stored?

Answer (score 2):

can you please provide more details about your environment - which version of H2O, platform.

I would recommend to re-try with the latest H2O (see http://h2o.ai/download).

Comment: Thank you, Michael! The beauty of an in-memory application like h2o is that when you close the program everything is gone. ;) The problem still persists, though. FYI: I was using the latest stable release from October.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @Michal that more info is needed.

If you're using R (I would recommend using R or Python) use `h2o.removeAll()`.

If you're using the Flow UI select `Data` -> `List All Frames` then select the check box for all frames and then click `Delete selected frames`.